# Unable to connect my Sony Vaio Laptop to LCD TV using HDMI Cable

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have Sony VAIO VPCEB24EN model laptop purchased few months ago and also a Sansui Fontes 3230 LCD TV. I need to connect my Laptop to TV using HDMI Cable but whenever I tries, my screen on Laptop goes black and the screen on TV starts showing some very higher resolution
4065*768 on 60 Hz. And nothing happens. My laptop drivers are updted. My Display Driver is ATI Radeon HD 5135.

Please help me out.

Laptop Environment 
OS:   Windows 7. 
Screen Resolution : 1366*768 on 60Hz
Display Driver : ATI Radeon HD 5135 (updated last night)